# RSpec 3.1 upgrade: namespaced routes not recognized any more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-routing

After an upgrade from Rails 3.0 to 3.2.21 and RSpec from 2.14 to 3.1, my API routes (namespaced, see below) aren't working any more. Specifically, they appear in `rake routes` and work in the browser in development mode, but they cause "Route not found" exceptions in tests and I cannot get them recognized in the console (but this might be my ignorance... any help appreciated).

Other (non-namespaced) routes work fine.

Here are the route definitions:

```
namespace :api, path: '', defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { format: :json, subdomain: 'api' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :foos, only: [:index] do
      post :bar, on: :collection
    end
  end
end
match '*path' => 'application#route_not_found'   # default 404 route
```

Here is the `rake routes` output:

```
bar_api_v1_foo_index POST   /v1/foo/bar(.:format) api/v1/foo#bar {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
          api_v1_foo DELETE /v1/foo/:id(.:format) api/v1/foo#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

Here is my spec (in `spec/integration/api_v1_foo_controller_spec.rb`):

```
require "spec_helper"
describe Api::V1::FooController do
  before do
    host! "api.#{host}"     # set subdomain, see http://elia.schito.me/2011/09/15/set-subdomain-in-rails-3-request-specs/
  end
  describe "POST" do
    it "should bar" do
      post "/v1/foo/bar"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the spec output:

Failures:

```
1) Api::V1::FooController POST should bar
   Failure/Error: post "/v1/foo/bar"
   ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches [POST] "/v1/foo/bar"
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
```

My feeble attempts at getting the routes to work in the console also fail, but for all Rails versions. It's probably the syntax (how do you use this?).

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path '/v1/foo/bar', method: :post, subdomain: 'api', format: :json
=> {:controller=>"application", :action=>"route_not_found", :path=>"v1/foo/bar"}
```

Why does the test above fail after the upgrade to Rails 3.2 and Rspec 3.1?

**Update**

This is probably an effect of a RoR bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8679

If I remove `subdomain: 'api'` inside the `constraints` block of the routes definition, all of Rails 3.2.21, 4.1.9 and 4-2-stable will accept the routes and work. If I force the spec to be a request spec **and** change the `host! "api.#{host}"` to `host! "api.example.com"`, the routing also works.

Is this intentional? Is there an alternate way of restricting a route to a specific subdomain?